# Using multiple patterns in egrep

Tags: regex, unix

I am trying to pull specific columns of data out of a text file, using multiple patterns in a regular expression.

The data I am trying to get is in the following order:

```
IP Address
Date & Time (DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS)
Protocol (3 characters)
Code (Numeric)
Data Quantity (Numeric)
User Agent (Text)
URL
```

I have built up the following expression in an expression builder site, to find the example below, but it does not seem to find anything when I execute through the terminal.

`([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3} - - \[([0-9]+)\/([A-Z][a-z]+)\/([0-9]+):([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+) \+[0-9]+\] "[A-Z]+ \/([A-Z]|[a-z]+).[a-z]+ [A-Z]+\/[0-9].[0-9]" ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) "-"? "[a-z]+\/[0-9].[0-9]`

This picks up

`"**207.46.98.61 - - [17/Oct/2004:09:10:50 +0100] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 25 "-" "msnbot/0.3**"`

In the expression builder this works, but when I run it against the text file in the terminal, it finds nothing at all.

I am using this in the terminal: `(text file) | egrep (regex)`.

If anybody could help, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong tool for that. Consider using `awk` or `python` (or whatever languages suites you) for more complex tasks.

Comment: Well i am intending to put the expression into awk once I have the regular expression working, but tbh I am not 100% on how I should be using regex to get the data that I need .